# Debian-Live stucked on grub

Tags: debian, grub2, live-usb, debian-installer, livecd

I downloaded Debian-Live and write it to USB.

When I boot from USB I get to grub and if I click Debian Live I see a screen blink like I clicked it but It wont boot, I'm still in GRUB. Pressing Install, Graphic install have same problem?

Comment: In order to help us help you, please tell us 1. the brand name and model of the computer and of the graphics chip/card; 2. Which iso file you are starting from (name of the iso file); 3. Did you check the iso file with md5sum (or some other checksum)? 4. Which tool did you use to create the USB boot drive?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/tags/nomodeset/info) kernel boot option. Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

Boot from the Debian live USB. You will see a Debian boot menu screen that looks like this:

[image]

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to edit a menu entry. This will bring up a GNU GRUB screen that looks like this:

[image]

Use the arrow keys to navigate when screen editing the above screen. Navigate to after the string on this screen that starts with `root=`. In this example screen the full string is `root=` followed by `UUID=` and a hexadecimal string as shown below:

```
root=UUID=3ca7fbd3-280e-4d70-8d84-2faa18a4b1cf
```

Immediately after this string replace `ro quiet splash` by `nomodeset quiet splash`. This change is only temporary — it will just be used once and GRUB won’t remember it in the future. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with the `nomodeset` option that was added. If you make a mistake, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to the previous screen.

To make the change permanent you need to add it to the `/etc/default/grub` file. Append `nomodeset` inside the quotes of the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="..."`. Then update your grub settings with `sudo update-grub`.

---

The smaller [netinst](https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/) CD image is easier to boot than the full size Debian image. The netinst CD image generally 150-300 MB, varies by architecture.

A "network install" or "netinst" Debian CD is a single CD which enables you to install the entire operating system. The network install CD contains the word "install" for a reason. It is not a Debian live CD, rather it is specifically used for installing Debian. This single CD contains just the minimal amount of software to start the installation and fetch the remaining packages over the internet. To write a CD image to a USB flash drive follow [these instructions](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb) from www.debian.org.

Comment: I need a Live CD